# Send GPS datas to UDP in broadcast mode with Socat

Tags: linux, networking

MUPLEX is a Linux script using SOCAT that can mix different input flows of real or emulate serial NMEA datas and share it between multiple applications using virtual serial ports and/or TCP. 
Now I would send datas to many terminals in UDP broadcast mode; I have try many combinations of adress/options, and look for examples from the web but without result.

ex in a simple form:

```
# parameters port for standard NMEA
params_port="b4800,raw,clocal=1,cs8,cstopb=0,parenb=0,crtscts=0,echo=0,icanon"
# GPS port
dev_gps=/dev/ttyUSB0

# network is 192.168.127.0, GPS is on the 192.168.127.1 machine
# testing broadcast
# first enable ping
echo 0 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts
ping -c5 -b 192.168.127.255
# result OK

# send datas to 10110 UDP port
socat -d -v FILE:$dev_gps,$params_port UDP4-DATAGRAM:192.168.127.255:10110,broadcast
```

No errors but any datas from the client side with:

```
netcat -u 192.168.127.1 10110
```

or

```
socat -d UDP:192.168.127.1:10110 -
```

If somebody have the solution, he is welcome !

The complete Muplex script is on:
http://marinux.tuxfamily.org

Comment: data is the plural of datum. There's nothing called "datas"

Answer (score 1):

I remember once having a similar problem, and the solution was to turn to "multicast" syntax, ie:
`socat -d -v FILE:$dev_gps,$params_port UDP4-RECVFROM:10110,ip-add-membership=224.1.0.1:192.168.127.10,fork`

Receiving end, `socat UDP4-DATAGRAM:224.1.0.1:10110,range=192.168.127.0/24 -`

I think the `x.x.x.255` thingy has been silently put to rest, but I'll have to look it up to make sure.

Comment: Thanks gmelis. Tried it, but 
1) client need to make <ENTER> and re <ENTER> to read message
2) client must be in standard form (ie UDP unattended packet, without customisation) to get compatible with chartplotters inputs.

Comment: Did you try without the `fork` option?

Comment: Yes, but any data comes after the first <ENTER>

Comment: In multicast mode, this work from server:
 `socat -d  FILE:$dev_gps,$params_port UDP4-DATAGRAM:230.0.0.1:23001,bind=:23000,reuseaddr,ip-add-membership=230.0.0.0:127.0.0.1 `
From client:

Comment: `socat -d UDP4-DATAGRAM:230.0.0.0:23000,bind=:23001,reuseaddr,ip-add-membership=230.0.0.1:127.0.0.1 -`
But it's not read by the navigational soft (ex PolarView) which need  a standard broadcast UDP packet as 192.168.x.x:23001

Comment: In that case, try this:
`socat -d -v FILE:$dev_gps,$params_port UDP4-DATAGRAM:192.168.127.255:10110,broadcast` on one side and
`socat UDP4-LISTEN:10110 -` on the receiving side.

Comment: `socat UDP4-LISTEN:10110,fork -` on the receiving side. I forgot the `fork` before.